# RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class null

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I installed Hive 0.9.0 and I get error when I run it:

```
./hive

Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/lib/hive-0.10.0/lib/hive-common-0.10.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties
Hive history file=/tmp/ec2-user/hive_job_log_ec2-user_201306091708_899006677.txt
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class null
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:293)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:669)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:613)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:192)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class null
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthenticator(HiveUtils.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:285)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class null
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.setConf(HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.java:53)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveUtils.getAuthenticator(HiveUtils.java:365)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load shims in class null
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:102)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.loadShims(ShimLoader.java:94)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.getHadoopShims(ShimLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.setConf(HadoopDefaultAuthenticator.java:51)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.ShimLoader.createShim(ShimLoader.java:99)
    ... 14 more
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure about the version?I can see `hive-0.10.0` in the trace. If it is Hive-0.9.0 then make sure you are using either hadoop-0.20.x and or hadoop-1.x.